# JavaScript - Use variable in string match

Tags: javascript, variables, match

I found several similar questions, but it did not help me. So I have this problem:

```
var xxx = "victoria";
var yyy = "i";
alert(xxx.match(yyy/g).length);
```

I don't know how to pass variable in match command. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [How do you pass a variable to a Regular Expression JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript). Search more ;)

Comment: One more thing: If you are using a variable to construct an regexp, cares should be taken that the variable might contain regexp special characters. e.g. if you pass "c++", the regex compiler will complain `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /c++/: Nothing to repeat`

Answer (score 244, accepted):

Although the match function doesn't accept string literals as regex patterns, you can use the constructor of the RegExp object and pass that to the String.match function:

```
var re = new RegExp(yyy, 'g');
xxx.match(re);
```

Any flags you need (such as /g) can go into the second parameter.

Comment: +1, this is the preferred way, BTW, if the argument passed to the `match` method is not a `RegExp` object, internally the `RegExp` constructor will be invoked using that value, so you can use a *string pattern*, e.g.: `"a123".match("\\d+")[0] === "123";`

Answer (score 18):

You have to use [RegExp object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) if your pattern is string

```
var xxx = "victoria";
var yyy = "i";
var rgxp = new RegExp(yyy, "g");
alert(xxx.match(rgxp).length);
```

If pattern is not dynamic string:

```
var xxx = "victoria";
var yyy = /i/g;
alert(xxx.match(yyy).length);
```

Comment: You get a imaginary downvote for using w3schools instead of MDN!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 9):

**Example.**  To find number of vowels within the string

```
var word='Web Development Tutorial';
var vowels='[aeiou]'; 
var re = new RegExp(vowels, 'gi');
var arr = word.match(re);
document.write(arr.length);
```

Answer (score 9):

For example:

```
let myString = "Hello World"
let myMatch = myString.match(/H.*/)
console.log(myMatch)
```

Or

```
let myString = "Hello World"
let myVariable = "H"
let myReg = new RegExp(myVariable + ".*")
let myMatch = myString.match(myReg)
console.log(myMatch)
```

Comment: it is helpful but when i use 

let myString = "Tata Nexon EV Tata"
let myVariable = "Tata"
let myReg = new RegExp("\b"+myVariable , "g")
let myMatch = myString.match(myReg)
console.log(myMatch)

not working

Answer (score 0):

for me anyways, it helps to see it used.
just made this using the "re" example:

```
var analyte_data = 'sample-'+sample_id;
var storage_keys = $.jStorage.index();
var re = new RegExp( analyte_data,'g');  
for(i=0;i<storage_keys.length;i++) { 
    if(storage_keys[i].match(re)) {
        console.log(storage_keys[i]);
        var partnum = storage_keys[i].split('-')[2];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of a simple and effective way to mock 'like' operator in JS. enjoy!

```js
const likePattern = '%%i%%%%%a';
const regexp = new RegExp(likePattern.replaceAll('%','.*'),"i");
console.log("victoria".match(regexp));
```

Answer (score -5):

```
xxx.match(yyy, 'g').length
```

Comment: This will work *only* in Firefox, and it isn't even documented. The specification states that the [`String.prototype.match`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.5.4.10) method expects only *one argument*. Using the `RegExp` constructor, as @Chris suggests is the preferred way.