# get string between two strings with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

How do I get a string between two strings using match with variables?  The following code works well if I use match with strings [Regular Expression to get a string between two strings in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642315/regular-expression-to-get-a-string-between-two-strings-in-javascript)  I also tried to apply the info at [JavaScript - Use variable in string match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172985/javascript-use-variable-in-string-match) :

```
var test = "My cow always gives milk";

var testRE = test.match("cow(.*)milk");
alert(testRE[1]);
```

But what if I have:

```
var firstvariable = "cow";
var secondvariable = "milk";

var test = "My cow always gives milk";
```

I've tried various things including:

```
var testRE = test.match("firstvariable(.*)secondvariable");
alert(testRE[1]);
```

and:

```
var testRE = testRE.match + '("' + firstvariable + "(.*)" + secondvariable +'")';
alert(testRE[1]);
```

Neither worked.

Comment: How should it handle a case like "My cow gives milk. I like milk". Should the match be not greedy: "cow gives milk" or greedy: "cow gives milk. I like milk"?

Comment: If you're gonna down vote, you could at least give a reason why.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try this:

```
test.match(new RegExp(firstvariable + "(.*)" + secondvariable));
```

Comment: It returns two parameters, and the fist is the full string

Comment: The result is an `Array` (or `null` if no match). There may be multiple matches depending on RegExp and tested text. The result contains 1.) **all matching results** and 2.) **each matching group** (parts matching regexp in parentheses).
E.g.: `"xxxxABCDEFxxxxx".match(new RegExp( "AB(CD)(EF)" ))` returns ["ABCDEF","CD","EF"]

Comment: Note 2: It is a greedy match (its result is the **longest matching string**). E.g.: "xxxxAAmCCmCCmCCxxxx".match(new RegExp( "AA(.*)CC" )) returns ["AAmCCmCCmCC","mCCmCCm"].

Comment: How it works if string contains '\n' at middle?

Comment: To make this non greedy so it matches the first instance instead then change "(.*)" to "(.*?)", so the full thing would be:
test.match(new RegExp(firstvariable + "(.*?)" + secondvariable));

Answer (score 14):

Use this code

```
const regExString = new RegExp(`(?<=${firstVariable}).*?(?=${secondVariable})`, "ig"); //set ig flag for global search and case insensitive

const testRE = regExString.exec("My cow always gives milk.");
if (testRE && testRE.length > 0) //RegEx has found something and has at least one entry.
{  
    alert(testRE[0]); //is the matched group if found
}
```

This matches only the middle part of the sentence.

1. `(?<="+firstvariable+")` finds but does not capture `cow` :: `lookbehind` is possible now.
2. `.*?` captures all characters between `cow` and `milk` and saves it in a group. `?` makes it lazy so it stops at milk.
3. `(?="+secondvariable+")` finds but does not capture `milk`. :: `lookahead`

You can test this below:

```js
const test = document.getElementById("testStringDiv").textContent;
let firstVariable = "";
let secondVariable = "";
function testString()
{
    firstVariable = document.querySelectorAll("input")[0].value; //first input;
    secondVariable = document.querySelectorAll("input")[1].value; //second input;
    
    //build the regex:
    //lookbehind is possible in JavaScript now: (?<=) sees if the content in the matched group is preceded by the first       variable, but does not capture this.
    //for the second variable we use the (?=) which is a lookahead and does the same as the lookbehind.
    //If there is a match, the string returned will be the one in the captured group (.*?)
    let regExString = new RegExp(`(?<=${firstVariable}).*?(?=${secondVariable})`, "ig");
    const testRE = regExString.exec(test);

    if (testRE && testRE.length > 0)
    {  
      document.getElementById("showcase").textContent = testRE[0]; //return second result.
    }
}
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", testString, true);
```

```html
<div id="testStringDiv">My cow always gives milk</div>
<div id="showcase">Result will display here...</div>
<input placeholder="enter first var"/><input placeholder="enter second var"/><button id="test">Search in between...</button>
```

Comment: Doesn't work if there are any newline characters in the base string. Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: In modern browsers since 2018 add ```s``` to the modifiers to enable ```dot``` to match line breaks.