# Add more than one variable in Javascript to work with the RegEx function

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172985/javascript-use-variable-in-string-match) post details how to include variables in regular expressions, but it only shows how to include one variable. I am currently using the match function for a regular expression to find the string in between a leading and trailing string. My code is below:

```
array = text.match(/SomeLeadingString(.*?)SomeTrailingString/g);
```

Now, how could I construct a regular expression that has the same functionality as this, but rather than having the two strings I'm using actually in the expression, I would like to be able to create them outside, like so:

```
var startString = "SomeLeadingString"
var endString = "SomeTrailingString"
```

So, my final question is, how can I include startString and endString into the regular expression that I listed above so that the functionality is the same? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `RegExp` object to concatenate strings to regex

```
const reg = new RegExp(`${startString}(\\w+)${endString}`,"g");
const matches = text.match(reg);
```

**Note**

When concatenating string, it is recommended to escape the none regex string: (the escape pattern is taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) answer)

`const escapeReg = (str)=>str.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');`

**Example**

We have the string `(.*)hello??` and we want to match the word between the `(.*)` and `??`

we will do something like:

```
const prefix = "(.*)";
const suffix = "??";
const reg = new RegExp(`${escapeReg(prefix)}(\\w+)${escapeReg(suffix)}`);
const result = "(.*)hello??".match(reg);
if(result){
   console.log(result[1]); //"hello"
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I want. I'll accept it as soon as I can.