# Using a variable in place of a number in a javascript match function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to split a string every n characters using a match function, but I figured that there are other uses to using a variable in a match function.

I know that the code

```
str.match(/.{0,3}/g);
```

will give me every three characters in a string, but

```
var n = 3;
str.match(/.{0,n}/g);
```

will not.

Comment: You can always construct regular expressions with [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Comment: is [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172985/javascript-use-variable-in-string-match) the answer you were searching for ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use a variable in a regular expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 4):

```
var n = 3;
str.match(new RegExp(".{0," + n + "}", "g"));
```